# pipx install eth-brownie error : Fatal error from pip prevented installation

Tags: python, brownie

was trying this `cmd:pipx install eth-brownie`, but encountered this error

[image]

I have tried, but not working:

1. reinstall `pipx`
2. using `pip install eth-brownie`
3. `pip install bitarray`, `cytoolz` and `lru-dict` seperately

**Error in Text**:
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
/Users/pilotbryan/.local/pipx/logs/cmd_2022-05-22_15.26.44_pip_errors.log

pip failed to build packages:
bitarray
cytoolz
lru-dict

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
error: legacy-install-failure

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please share the error [as text and not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)?

Comment: Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    /Users/pilotbryan/.local/pipx/logs/cmd_2022-05-22_15.26.44_pip_errors.log

pip failed to build packages:
    bitarray
    cytoolz
    lru-dict

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    error: legacy-install-failure

Comment: Could you please copy the error directly as a text and paste it in the question while keeping the original formatting of the error?

Comment: [Edit] instead of commenting to update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the Command Line Tools package- that's why pip install was failing. You can try to download the tool using:
`xcode-select --install` in terminal. If it does not work for you, try resetting the xcode install. I found useful tutorial in here: https://gist.github.com/Justintime50/2349ff5e62555aa097acbf519bbc27af

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the Python version is upgraded to a major version on a machine on which pipx was installed and used before.

The solution is to remove the ~/.local/pipx/shared folder

```
rm -rfv ~/.local/pipx/shared
```

Or just backup

```
mv ~/.local/pipx/shared ~/.local/pipx/shared.bak
```

Then you can `pipx install eth-brownie`